# jQuery single click event for N elements with Id optionN

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following HTML

```
<input id="Option1" name="Option1" type="checkbox" value="..." />
<input id="Option2" name="Option2" type="checkbox" value="..." />
<input id="Option3" name="Option3" type="checkbox" value="..." />
..........................
..........................
<input id="OptionN" name="OptionN" type="checkbox" value="..." />
```

Where N can be any number, from 1 to 500.

I want to write a **single click event** (jquery/JavaScript), so when a user click on any checkbox this method should be called.

Comment: Use a common selector

Comment: You mean on click of 1 checkbox ,all checkboxes should get checked?

Comment: why this question is getting down vote, might be you are smart enough but It did not click to my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `MyClass` class to checkbox

```
<input id="Option1" name="Option1" type="checkbox" class="MyClass" value="..." />
<input id="Option2" name="Option2" type="checkbox" class="MyClass" value="..." />
<input id="Option3" name="Option3" type="checkbox" class="MyClass" value="..." />
```

And use the following code

```
$(".MyClass").on("click", function(){
    // Do stuff
})
```

Comment: There are other checkbox on the page, for which I don't want to call this method

Comment: @AliAdravi set some class and access by that class name

Comment: @AliAdravi ,then on which crieteria ,You dont want to call this method?

Comment: @AliAdravi: Put the class on those checkboxes that you want the method to call, don't put the class on those you don't.

Answer (score 1):

If you couldn't set a common name or class to the elements, you could use the jQuery [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][id^="Option"]').on('click', function(){
    // Do stuff
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your markup and if there's a form surrounding your inputs:

```
$("form").on("click", "input[name^='Option'])", function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Very popular mistake: id must be unique. If you want to target number (class) of elements you should use `class`:

```
<input id="Option1" class="option" name="Option1" type="checkbox" value="..." />
<input id="Option2" class="option" name="Option1" type="checkbox" value="..." />
```

JS:

```
$('.option').click(function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it to a table when I click on a button i can remove it 
so for your question I think that first of all put your input checkboxes in a DIV and give it an id

AND you give to each input the same class name

```
   <div id="div_id">
       <input id="Option1" name="Option1" type="checkbox" class="input_class" value="..." />
       <input id="Option2" name="Option2" type="checkbox" class="input_class"  value="..." />
       <input id="Option3" name="Option3" type="checkbox" class="input_class"  value="..." />
        ..........................
        ..........................
       <input id="OptionN" name="OptionN" type="checkbox" class="input_class"  value="..." />
   </div>
```

So using JQuery you can do smth like that :

```
$("#div_id").on('click', '.input_class', function() {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));         
});
```

Hope this peace of code may help you :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use ID based *starts-with* selector.

```
$("[id^='Option']").change(function(){

    //your function

})
```